# Поместить в массив число, полученное от даты

Tags: javascript

Есть массив и дата :

---

```
var m = [0,0,0];
var t = new Date();
```

---

```
alert(t.getDate()+t.getHours()+t.getMinutes()); // показывает, например, 272157;
```

Как правильно поместить это 272157 как число в последний элемент массива?

```
m[2] = t.getDate()+t.getHours()+t.getMinutes(); // складывает и вносит число 105;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если очень просто то можно сделать так :)

```
m[2] = '' + t.getDate()+t.getHours()+t.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Действительно, так работает, большое спасибо.

Comment: @Alex, лидирующего нуля нет.

Comment: Если нужен лидирующий ноль самый простой спсоб сделать так
`m[2] = '' + ((t.getDate() < 10) ? '0' : '') + t.getDate() + ((t.getHours() < 10) ? '0' : '') + t.getHours() + ((t.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' : '') + t.getMinutes()`

Comment: Спасибо, очень ценное замечание и помощь.